# load-grunt-configs and bower.install() using grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I am trying to devide my existing Gruntfile into more smaller ones to make having an overview easier. However I ran into a bump. I am using bower.install to install my project dependencies.
My folder structure looks something like this:

```
package.json
bower.json
config
--install.js
--default.js //Empty for now
gruntfile.js
```

My Gruntfile right now looks like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var npmDependencies = require('./package.json').devDependencies;
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  var configs = {
    config : {
      paths : {
        "build" : ["grunts/*.js*", "package.json", "bower.json", "Gruntfile.js"],
      }
    }
  };

  var loadConfigs = require( 'load-grunt-configs' );
  configs = loadConfigs( grunt, configs );
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig( configs );
}
```

My install.js looks like so:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var done = grunt.async();
  var bower = require('bower').commands;
  bower.install().on('end', function(data) {
    done();
  }).on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    done();
  });
}
```

However this does not work as I am receiving the error:

```
>> TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'async'
```

If I remove all that async-clutter (which I ultimately want to keep), so that the file looks a lot simpler:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var bower = require('bower').commands;
    bower.install();
}
```

I still receive the following error:

```
>> TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

I am fairly new to this topic and so far (having everything in one file) it worked fine. Big question now: How do I get back to that point ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with `install.js`:

1) The [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt) object does not expose the async function, this is the reason for the first error. The [async](http://gruntjs.com/api/inside-tasks#this.async) function is available for grunt tasks so it should be called from within a task.
 2) When [using node modules for configuration](https://github.com/creynders/load-grunt-configs#using-node-modules-for-configuration), *load-grunt-configs* expects a function which returns an object, for example:

```
//config/jshint.js
module.exports = function(grunt, options){
     return {
         gruntfile       : {
             src : "Gruntfile.js"
         }
     }
 }
```

In your case the function return nothing and *load-grunt-configs* fails with the `Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined` error.

The following should work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  return grunt.registerTask("bower", function() {
      var done = this.async();
      var bower = require('bower').commands;
      bower.install().on('end', function(data) {
        done();
      }).on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }).on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        done();
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late feedback. You are right, there were several things wrong. But: The possibillity shown by you here is only one variant, as far as I understood the documentation you linked. I am referring to the code example right above the return a function part, the Example js file returning an object part. Somehow however that won't work for me.

Comment: @stiller_leser I tested this sample before posting it. can you please specify what is not working?

Comment: You're Code example works totally fine for me (aside from an issue that he would not find the bower.json file - which is fixed now). See here for the code sample I am referring to: http://pastebin.com/idZgQ0bx - But I switched to load-grunt-config by now which is working fine for me. Chances are high, that I just had a small error in my config somewhere. Thanks for your help though!